# SDL - Can't close program even using the task manager

Tags: c++, windows-7, sdl, codeblocks

The program compiles 'correctly'(.exe file appears) but it can't be closed even when I shutdown my laptop(task manager doesn't work too). The only way to close it is turning off. What's wrong? Also, Code::Blocks displays this when I compile project:

```
Running project post-build steps
XCOPY (invalid)\bin\*.dll bin\Debug\ /D /Y
ЌҐ ­ ©¤Ґ­ д ©«: *.dll
‘Є®ЇЁа®ў ­® д ©«®ў: 0.
Process terminated with status 4
```

Comment: Maybe your Antivirus is the problem. If it is not that you will have to somehow produce more details. You are basically asking us to debug an issue with your OS given almost no information.

Answer (score 1):

Given that no information, I'm guessing you have the main loop in your program  but you didn't use the `SDL_Quit` enumerator in your main loop to check if you try to quit your program (alt + f4 and 'X' etc.) Basically a simple SDL application should look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main (int argc, char* args[] )
{

 SDL_Event event;
 bool exit = false;
 
 SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow ("title",
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        1000,
                                        500,
                                        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)

 while(exit == false)
 {
  while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) >= 0)
  {
     if(event.type == SDL_Quit)
     {
      exit = true; // when this becomes true, the program terminates 
     }
     //other events goes here
   }
 }
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

see if this code works in your computer.

Comment: Small note: `SDL_Quit` is a function. `SDL_QUIT` is an event.